# iOS 8 pushViewController not working, in iOS 7 everything works as expected, zero code changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

When I run my app on *iOS 7 things work as expected*. When I run my app on *iOS 8 things do NOT* work as expected. This is all without making a single edit to the codebase.

Specifically, I'm trying to "push" a new view controller on the stack and *in iOS 8 nothing happens*. <-- That's the bug, nothing happens. No crash, just nothing.

At first I thought it might be storyboard related and so switched from triggering my push segue via `performSegueWithIdentifier` to just manually loading it from the storyboard using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and then presenting it via `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];`.

Either of the above techniques works on iOS 7. *However, BOTH approaches fail when running my app on an iOS 8 device*. Furthermore, I've noted weird behavior in the debugger/NSLog. In iOS 7 when I run `NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController)` I get (as expected):

`self.navigationController = <UINavigationController: 0x145986b0>`

In iOS 8, I ALSO get (as expected):

`self.navigationController = <UINavigationController: 0x15d646db0>`

Meanwhile, at that same point in the code, when I insert a break and then check things out via the console like so: `(lldb) po self.navigationController` In iOS 7, I get  (as expected):

`(lldb) po self.navigationController
<UINavigationController: 0x175810b0>`

HOWEVER, in iOS 8, I get:

`(lldb) po self.navigationController
error: property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'PHMenuTableViewController *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression`

In both of the above `po` examples I'm building with my "Debug" build config.

Ultimately, I'm just trying to push a view controller. My original code was using a segue. While trying to debug this I moved away from the segue to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];`. Both approaches work on iOS 7 as expected. However, no matter what I do I cannot get the push to work on iOS 8, nothing happens at all as if the navigation controller is `nil` or something when it's not!

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to NSLog the `viewDidLoad` of the VC that should appear? is it fired?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Just added a break in `viewDidLoad`. When running on iOS 8 `viewDidLoad` is *not* getting called.

Comment: Have you tried to use your first method `performseguewithidentifier` but using a `modal segue` instead of a `push segue`? just to see if it's a problem related to the `navigation controller` or to the `viewController` that should be presented. And have you got the method `prepare for segue`? Have you tried to insert breaks in there?

Comment: Great questions, thank you. `performSegueWithIdentifier` seems to be working fine. When I add breaks to `prepareForSegue` the breaks do get triggered. For testing I've moved away from using segues and am instead using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` & `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];`. Now here's NEW INFO: When I use `[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:^{}];`, then `myVC`'s `viewDidLoad` method DOES get called, whereas with `pushViewController` it does NOT. In both cases nothing happens on screen though!

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer to solving this issue now that I'm seeing what's unique here and that's that my menu vc is being presented via a custom transition delegate, `menuVC.transitioningDelegate = self`. The app's view hierarchy looks like: Nav VC > Base VC > Menu VC > Other VCs. Base VC presents Menu VC via custom modal transition. It's the Menu VC that can't push/present any other VCs...

Comment: Furthermore, when I try and dismiss the Menu VC I'm getting this error, "attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear.". There must be new requirements for setting up custom transitions in iOS 8 that is the root cause of this issue. Any ideas? I'll keep digging...

Comment: Would it change anything if you use `[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];` ?

Comment: That gets it so the presented view controller's viewDidLoad method gets called but doesn't have any effect on what the user sees. They tap and nothing happens still.

Comment: Also tried with `completion:nil`? Anyway are you sure you set the ViewController with that Class name? If the `viewDidLoad` gets fired it could be a problem of that VC, try comment everything and see if it loads a black VC

Answer (score 2):

My situation is just similar to yours.

I have a VC named InventoryMatrixEditViewController and its is presented by customized modal presentation. And in this VC there is a method called in -(void)viewDidLoad; to setup the layout:

```
- (void)_setupLayout
{
    if (_isToCreateNewMatrix) {
        //[self.view addSubview:self.attributesTableViewController.view];
        [self.attributesTableViewController addNewAttributeItem];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.attributesTableViewController
                                             animated:Yes];
        return;
    }
....
```

if the animated flag is Yes, sometimes the viewDidLoad of the pushed view (self.attributesTableViewController) will not be called(strangely not every time the error will be triggered), but the app is not crashed, just present a blank modalView and even the navigationBar is not set.

But if the animated flag is NO, everything is ok.

I wonder if it is a bug or the Apple just push people not to activate the animation if the view is first presented modally.

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: It's not worded like an answer, but setting the animated flag to NO definitely works for iOS 8 (where the existing code works for iOS 7).